# Performant way to validate numerics or range of numerics with RegexValidator in Django

Tags: python, regex, django

## The problem

I have a model that has a [`CharField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#charfield) field, where the field can only accept numerics or a range of numerics. The numerics must either have a leading zero if they are decimal and are <1, and if they are a whole number, they cannot have a trailing period unless the trailing period has a trailing zero. The ranges are delineated using a hyphen and must not contain any spaces. I'm using Django's [`RegexValidator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/validators/#regexvalidator) to validate the field.

**Note:** I don't care if the ranges are reversed (e.g. `6-3`, `10.3-0.13`)

These are some examples of values that should pass in the validator:

- `5`
- `0.42`
- `5.0`
- `5-6`
- `5-6.0`
- `0.5-6.13`
- `5.1-6.12`
- `13.214-0.1813`

These should be invalid values for the validator:

- `5.`
- `5.1.3`
- `5.13.215`
- `5-13.2-14`
- `.13-1.31`
- `5-6.`
- `5 - 6`

## My current solution

```
my_field = models.CharField(
    ...
    validators=[
        RegexValidator(
            r'^[0-9]+([.]{1}[0-9]+){0,1}([-]{1}[0-9]+([.]{0,1}[0-9]+){0,1}){0,1}$',
            message='Only numerics or range of numerics are allowed.'
        )
    ]
)
```

## What I need help at

As you can see, this is a pretty gnarly regex pattern, and I'm not so sure if this pattern is performant. I'm not a regex guru so I'd appreciate if someone offers a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this regex pattern:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?$
```

This says to:

```
\d+         match an initial whole number component
(?:\.\d+)?  followed by an optional decimal component
(?:
    -       range separator
\d+         second whole number
(?:\.\d+)?  with optional decimal component
)?          the range being optional
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation. The explanation is really helpful!